# How to replace the escape unicode characters like \u001A in a string to empty spaces

Tags: sql, regex, databricks, hql, html-escape-characters

I have a string like A, with unicode escape characters. How can I replace those characters with empty spaces in SQL?

### A

> My Name is **\u001A**Vinaykumar. I am **\u001A**From AndhraPradesh. I have completed my B.tech\u001A in Osmania University

### B

> My Name is Vinaykumar. I am From AndhraPradesh. I have completed my B.tech in Osmania University

I have tried to use the regex function but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `REPLACE` function to do this: `REPLACE(string, old_string, new_string)`

Your function would look like this.

```
SELECT REPLACE(A, '\u001A', '');
```